# Normalization in tensor networks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, time-evolution, spin-chains, tensor-network

I am trying to implement the iTEBD algorithm for the $PXP$ model, i.e, the hamiltonian is

$$H = \sum_iP_{i-1}X_iP_{i+1}.$$

Here $P$ is the projector onto the ground state and $X$ is the usual pauli x matrix.

I aim to time evolve a certain initial state and record certain observables. To do so, I initialized my iMPS (infinite Matrix Product State), and as a check, I took the overlap of this with itself. As I expected, this gave me a result of 1. However, it appears that as I time evolve my state, the normalization strays further from unity, and by the last time step, it is of the order 1e5. I know that we perform a truncation in each time step, but my question is can this introduce such a large error?

I have used a trotter step of 0.01, and a bond dimension of 50, and I have evolved for 20-time steps. For context, I am trying to time-evolve a state that resembles the Neel state, i.e it looks like $|...0101...\rangle$

Edit: it appears that the norm squared is jumping around rather than just increasing
[image: Plot of norm over time]

The link to my code is below for anyone who is interested

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12p8c6UJB5M49tOJqbTno1bZpUfc_I-mB?usp=sharing

As this is the first time I am working with tensor networks and I haven’t seen any examples online of 3-body hamiltonians, I would also like to get it cleared if there would be any particular differences in applying 3-body vs 2-body hamiltonians. Right now what I do is contract 3 site tensors, apply the time evolution operator, and SVD out the resulting tensor.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to the [Computational Science site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Miyase How much do you know about the topic of the question? This is about a simulation method used for time evolution of quantum many-body systems, and thus rather specific to physics. Conversely, I would be interested to see at least one question at Comp. Science answering a question in that direction -- I couldn't find one with a quick search. On the other hand, I know that here, there are at least a few people who could answer this.

Comment: @Souroy If you have an error, it will accumulate - so to decrease the error you need smaller Trotter steps. But I would think the norm in iTEBD, done the usual way, should get *smaller* by truncation, not larger. -- I'd suggest doing sanity checks to see if you have a bug.

Comment: It would also help to give some details of your algorithms: Size of Trotter step, for how long do you evolve. Maybe even a plot of the norm vs. time? What is the truncation error you make in each step?

Comment: The plot looks fishy. (BTW, typically a log-y-axis is better.) *If* it grows, the error should grow "nicely" (probably exponentially). Did you previously write a simpler iTEBD code (2-body Hamiltonian)?

Comment: BTW: You get negative norms?! Think about that.

Comment: To follow up on your edit: Start by writing a 2-site Hamiltonian code first. If you get this to work, slowly move to the 3-site case. And write a minimalistic code from scratch. (There's no reason why your code has a routine for creating Gell-Mann matrices.) -- Then, test your 3-site code against 2-site Hamiltonians. -- And figure out why your norm is negative, this is plain wrong! In fact, your code looks like you want to keep your state normalized, so if this fails there is some serious issue.

Comment: BTW, it is not clear how you realize the 3-site code, and there is AFAIK not one standard way. So you should describe what you do in detail (formulas! not just words!). E.g. you need to take care to preserve the lambda-gamma-form in that case, from a quick glimpse at your code it is unclear how you achieve that.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll do that